# Docker command hang on container

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I have created one container by using `msql-server:5.7`. After creating, I am able to access it without a problem. But after a couple of minutes, all Docker commands in the container becomes unresponsive. I cannot inspect, stop or kill. Is there a way I can debug? I have some other containers running as well, but those are OK.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                          NAMES
ca471079614b        mysql/mysql-server:5.7   "/entrypoint.sh mysq…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)         33060/tcp                      db
$ docker info
Containers: 8
 Running: 8
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 94
Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
Storage Driver: overlay2
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Supports d_type: true
 Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729
runc version: b2567b37d7b75eb4cf325b77297b140ea686ce8f
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.0-1047-aws
Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.42GiB
Name: ip-172-31-12-60
ID: I7FQ:XUUN:UU5C:KVJI:JPDT:L2BV:B3EQ:5LHI:5XD5:PSWP:NI7Y:BDX7
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:   17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:11:19 2017
 OS/Arch:   linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:  17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:    Wed Dec 27 20:09:53 2017
  OS/Arch:  linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-12-60 4.4.0-1047-aws #56-Ubuntu SMP Sat Jan 6 19:39:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: check `journalctl` command output when the issue occurs

Comment: does `docker logs CONTAINER_NAME` give you anything?

Comment: docker logs xxx hangs as well

Comment: do you have sufficient ram memory?

Comment: $ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            31G        3.9G         12G        9.2M         15G         27G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after couple of day trying, it turns out I change my instance-type from m4.2xlarge to m4.4xlarge. and after trying 1 days. it seems the problem solved. I have no idea why but it is good so far

Answer (score 0):

Are you double sure this is not docker specific issue? Maybe unsupported kernel version? All logs are dumped to a log file inside the volume in the /var/lib/docker/volumes directory. Try running the container without the -d flag so all output goes to stdout directly to identify the problem.

Comment: all docker command hang on container...so no way I can running any docker command on it

Comment: What image is it anyway? The official MySQL image is `mysql:tag`

Comment: mysql:5.7 and I have try mysql:lates as well

Comment: What's your OS/kernel version?

Comment: Linux ip-172-31-12-60 4.4.0-1047-aws x86_64